# XML sidecar in SharePoint for Digital Asset Management

Tags: xml, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, dam

My organization is moving all of it's content to SharePoint 2013 over the next year. My issue is with digital asset management and the OOB WYSIWYG media library you get with the platform: it doesn't embed metadata on photos, video, etc back to the original source file.

The only workaround I can think of to keep our content uniform and extensible is an XML sidecar.

CAN ANYONE RECOMMEND good resources for tacking an XML sidecar to files stored in SharePoint 2013. I don't want my organization's hundreds of thousands of photos, videos, audio recordings, etc to be totally unmanageable should we decide to use a different platform in the future.

PLEASE HELP.

Thanks.

Comment: Maintaining a metadata xml file for a resource is bit tricky and also for search you might have to build some parsers etc for extracting the properties. is your metadata list huge? can't you have different content types?

Comment: Hi @Nikunj. We can definitely create multiple content types, but ultimately, I'm thinking that it might not be worth shoe-horning a variety of different media into what is essentially built as a DMS. We don't even have our assets (images, videos) collected just yet, but I'm assuming it'll be in the range of 40,000 - 50,000.